# Advise on setting up maven for multiple projects

Tags: java, spring, maven, ant

I was looking at some open source projects and noticed they have a setup like:

```
/app1/pom.xml
/app1/app1-mod1/pom.xml
/app1/app1-mod2/pom.xml
/app1/app1-mod3/pom.xml
```

So there is a master pom, and then all the modules have pom.xml also.

So in my situation I have the following:

```
1. spring mvc application
2. spring mvc application
3. shared model/db layer
```

So I guess I should be following the multiple pom.xml setup?

If yes, how will I get #3 to build before #2 and #1.

Should I be dropping down to ant to perform the actual build?

Any tutorials that you guys know of to walk me through this process?

I'm coding in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven will calculated the [dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) by itself it you setup your POMs so that
module #1 and #2 both depend on #3 maven will build #3 first without any additional configuration required.

The layout you use (multi module) is also required for the release plugin.

See also [A Multi-module Project](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html)

Comment: great link, multi project examples are perfect.

Answer (score 3):

The Maven reactor will build the modules in an appropriate order, you can tell it what you think the best way is by sorting them how you want.

I have a similar project setup like this:

```
<artifactId>root</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Root</name>

<modules>
    <module>event</module>
    <module>admin</module>
    <module>public</module>
</modules>
```

This is then used as a parent by the other modules. The event library is used in both the admin and public webapp modules. In the webapp modules define something like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Events -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>event</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

A **mvn install** from the root works beautifully.

Comment: Note that the parent and child projects in this example are linked in two different ways: by inheritance and by composition. You can perfectly well inherit from a parent POM without being a subproject of it, or inversely, be a subproject of another project without inheriting from its POM.